# git clone from a vps

Tags: git, ssh, vps

I'm having some trouble cloning my repository

```
$git clone ssh://root@8x.12x.9x.21x:/repo repo
Cloning into 'repo'...
fatal: '/repo' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

while i'm having no such trouble cloning on the vps itself. nor did i have trouble pushing to it from another computer.

```
$ ssh root@8x.12x.9x.21x
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 2.6.32-042stab111.11 x86_64)

* Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
Last login: Tue Mar  8 12:29:47 2016 from 80.79.35.115
root@vps:~# ls
deployment_test  my-project  repo
root@vps:~# git clone repo repo2
Cloning into 'repo2'...
done.
```

Does anybody know what might be the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
git clone ssh://root@8x.12x.9x.21x:/root/repo
```

You may omit the colon because you’re using the standard port.

```
git clone ssh://root@8x.12x.9x.21x:/root/repo
```

For completeness, SSH clone URLs also work as in

```
git clone root@8x.12x.9x.21x:/root/repo
```

or with a relative path because it is in root’s home directory.

```
git clone root@8x.12x.9x.21x:repo
```